# Performance Issue with Scrollview above MapView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

We are developing a map based application which displays large number of annotations above the map using MKMapKit.

We are using a scrollview placed above MapView for differentiating between pinch and drag gestures. We are able to differentiate between pinch and drag but the responsiveness of the Application becomes sluggish while dragged.

We will appreciate any suggestions for improving responsiveness of map while using the scrollview above MapView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Combining MKMapView and UIScrollView was always a bad idea. Try not to use it. Use UIView with gesture recognizers over the map instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We tried using the UIView but we cannot drag(Pan) the map using it.

Comment: How did you use this view? Was it over the map?

Comment: I would suggest you to add mkmap as a subview of your view, maybe then along with the map drag you will also receive UIView move events

Comment: We have tried using mkmapview as a subview of another view but we cannot detect beginning of pinching gesture.